# Paypal Recurring Direct payment issue

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

For the last two days I am trying to figure out this issue but so far i've been unable to solve it. I am successfully creating/deleting Recurring profiles in Paypal Express checkout(sandbox mode).Now im facing issues with the direct payment. Yesterday I created two profiles using the following piece of code and got the responses as shown below. Unfortunately my account activity isnt showing any of this profile creation. Can you tell me why? At the same time I created it with express checkout and that activity is present in my account.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
encoder.add("VERSION", "86.0");
encoder.add("METHOD","CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile");
encoder.add("DESC","Cloudstream10UserPack");
encoder.add("INITAMT","25.29");
encoder.add("FAILEDINITAMTACTION","ContinueOnFailure");
encoder.add("BILLINGPERIOD","Day");
encoder.add("BILLINGFREQUENCY","1");
encoder.add("PROFILESTARTDATE","2015-06-04T00:00:00Z");
encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE","USD");
encoder.add("COUNTRYCODE","US");
encoder.add("MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS","3");
encoder.add("AMT",amount);
encoder.add("CREDITCARDTYPE",cardType);     
encoder.add("ACCT",acct);                       
encoder.add("EXPDATE",expdate);
encoder.add("CVV2",cvv2);
encoder.add("FIRSTNAME",firstName);
encoder.add("LASTNAME",lastName);
```

response

```
{VERSION=86.0,
BUILD=16837281, 
TRANSACTIONID=03H59687N1667990E, 
PROFILEID=I-4K9NPGAHRM34, 
PROFILESTATUS=PendingProfile, 
ACK=Success, CORRELATIONID=2f485d30ec1f4, 
TIMESTAMP=2015-06-03T08:25:38Z}
```

In the second profile I removed INITAMT and FAILEDINITAMTACTION and got the following response:

```
{VERSION=86.0, 
BUILD=16837281, 
PROFILEID=I-W0CRGLBCJTBB, 
PROFILESTATUS=ActiveProfile, 
ACK=Success, 
CORRELATIONID=6002b88159503, 
TIMESTAMP=2015-06-03T11:58:02Z}
```

I made third profile right now and got response and when I check the activity I got nothing updated

```
{VERSION=86.0, 
BUILD=16837281, 
PROFILEID=I-YV4LTS1JGUJ1, 
PROFILESTATUS=ActiveProfile, 
ACK=Success, 
CORRELATIONID=c322b816c1403, 
TIMESTAMP=2015-06-05T07:25:41Z}
```

Comment: The response is showing that the call was successful, so the profile has to be showing up in a sandbox account somewhere (or live account if this was run live.)  Is there a chance you have different credentials setup that are getting used with EC vs. Pro?

Comment: @AndrewAngell ryt now i am testing both of them in sandbox...but i am going to check the credentials part as u pointed..thnx fr u reply..

Comment: @AndrewAngell sir I have checked , I am using the same credentials as for EC ...also created third profile and response is 
{VERSION=86.0, BUILD=16837281, PROFILEID=I-YV4LTS1JGUJ1, PROFILESTATUS=ActiveProfile, ACK=Success, CORRELATIONID=c322b816c1403, TIMESTAMP=2015-06-05T07:25:41Z}

Comment: That has to be showing up then.  If not, you'll need to submit a ticket to MTS, but you'll probably need to put together a video or screenshots or something so they can see the request/response for both EC and Pro, and then also see that it truly isn't showing up in the account.  That just doesn't make sense, but if it's really happening it must be a problem with the account.  On that note, you could try creating a fresh sandbox account to see if you still have the same problem.